# Android Studio | Problem saving Object Arraylist by SharedPreferences

Tags: java

Basically I'm trying to save a arraylist to a shared preferences and then I can close the app and open lately to with the old data inside of the arraylist but I'm getting some problems creating the method.

Here the code:

Arraylist:

```
public Articles articles = new Articles();
```

Method to save:

```
public void saveFile(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Container.this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(getContainer());
    editor.putString("Saves", json);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Here the Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bitinbyte.ivycambridgebrassery, PID: 29267
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bitinbyte.ivycambridgebrassery/com.bitinbyte.ivycambridgebrassery.newCount}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:142)
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:537)
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:526)
    at com.bitinbyte.ivycambridgebrassery.Container.saveFile(Container.java:170)
    at com.bitinbyte.ivycambridgebrassery.newCount.onCreate(newCount.java:43)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: You're passing `Container.this` to `getDefaultSharedPreferences`. What is it? Couldn't you pass a context object instead?

Comment: What is the difference between both? I'm despairing with this...

Comment: But basically Container.this is the class where I have the method saveFile and the arraylist

Comment: Try using `MyApplication.getAppContext()` (where MyApplication is the name of the class that extends `Application`). If that works, don't keep using it. Replace by a context object more close to the Activity that calls `saveFile`.